# How to use gdal.warp cutline option?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, ogr

I am trying to get tiles of raster contained within a bounding polygon in a shapefile. My output raster should have values for all pixels within the polygon feature, and NA or 0 everywhere outside the bounding polygon. I am trying to use gdal.warp for this. This is the code which I tried, and while it works to trim the original raster to the extent of the polygon, I am not able to make the pixel values zero outside the polygon.

```
InputImage = 'inputs.tif'
Shapefile = 'outcrops.shp'
RasterFormat = 'GTiff'
VectorFormat = 'ESRI Shapefile'

# Open datasets
Raster = gdal.Open(InputImage, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
Projection = Raster.GetProjectionRef()

VectorDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName(VectorFormat)
VectorDataset = VectorDriver.Open(Shapefile, 0) # 0=Read-only, 1=Read-Write
layer = VectorDataset.GetLayer()

feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef() 
minX, maxX, minY, maxY = geom.GetEnvelope() # Get bounding box of the shapefile feature

OutTileName = 'SomeTileName.tif'
OutTile = gdal.Warp(OutTileName, Raster, format=RasterFormat, outputBounds=[minX, minY, maxX, maxY], dstSRS=Projection, cutlineLayer=layer, cropToCutline=True)
OutTile = None # Close dataset

Raster = None
VectorDataset.Destroy()
print("Done.")
```

Can someone point me towards where I am going wrong?

Comment: With gdalwarp you would set nodata with -dstnodata or -dstalpha. Do something similar with your python.

Comment: OutTile = gdal.Warp(OutTileName, Raster, format=RasterFormat, dstSRS=Projection, dstNodata=999, cutlineLayer=Shapefile, options=['COMPRESS=DEFLATE'])

Tried this, but I am not the getting the clipped raster. Instead I am getting the original raster in the output file.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution I've been able to come up with makes use `gdal.Warp` in combination with [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html). I've been tackling some days with this problem and just decided to give this a try, and it worked like a prayer:

```
import gdal

# Allow for verbose exception reporting
gdal.UseExceptions()

# Build the OGR SQL
sql = "SELECT * FROM your_shapefile"

# Clip the input Raster
result = gdal.Warp('path/to/clipped_raster',
                   '/path/to/raster',
                   cutlineDSName='/path/to/Vector',
                   cutlineSQL=sql,
                   cropToCutline=True)

# Initiate writing operations
result = None
```

As you can see, we don't read any datasets ourselves. We only provide the paths to `gdal.Warp` and the rest is taken care of. Keep in mind though, that I'm not aware of you shapefile dataset and the SQL-clause is only an example. There are some gotchas also, which are not directly related to the `gdal.Warp`, such as matching coordinate systems.

In case your shapefile would contain multiple instances, such as multiple crop fields, you could try implementing a `WHERE`-clause in to the SQL. Example of this would look like

```
SELECT * FROM your_shapefile WHERE a_field = 'a_value'
```

I truly hope this helps you!

Answer (score 5):

This is easier to do with gdal_translate and gdal_rasterize (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html, http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html)

```
#Read in datasets
Raster = gdal.Open('/path/to/raster')
VectorDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName(VectorFormat)
Vector = VectorDriver.Open('/path/to/.shp', 0)

#Get shapefile bounding box:
layer = Vector.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
minX, maxX, minY, maxY = geom.GetEnvelope()
bbox = (minX,maxY,maxX,minY) #Reorder bbox to use with gdal_translate

#Clip raster to shapefile bounding box
clip = gdal.Translate('path/to/output', Raster, projWin=bbox)

#Create new values
output = gdal.Rasterize(clip, [1], Vector, burn_values = [1], init_value = [0])
```

Translate is a better method of cutting rasters by a bounding box than warp because it's a little faster and uses slightly less memory to perform the operation.

The rasterize function is used to burn values into any raster data format according to a vector geometry.  We initialize the raster with a value of 0 and assign a new value of 1 everywhere inside of the geometry.

I don't have data to test this code on, so I can't guarantee that it will work, but it should get you going on the right track.

---

It would also be relatively straightforward to throw the clipped image from gdal.Warp into numpy to add a value of 0 to all pixels outside of the geometry.  Assuming we are starting with your output (OutTile):

```
band = OutTile.GetRasterBand(1) #Assuming we are working with one band output
array = band.ReadAsArray() #Numpy array
array[np.where(array!=1)] = 0 #Assuming all values inside polygon have value of 1
band.WriteArray(array)
band.FlushCache()
OutTile = None
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want the pixel values of the original raster to remain for pixels inside the polygon, and NoDATA outside the polygon. Your method makes it 1 inside, 0 outside. How do I keep the original raster values inside the polygon in the final output?