# Cutting out polygon by GDAL in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, polygon, rasterio

I use the rasterio to cutting out polygons from TIFFs. The problem is rasterio is too slow. I am looking for something another and I would like to use GDAL but I don't know how to write the code.

By rasterio I use:

```py
import rasterio

tiff = '/mnt/gis_matrix/geo_tiff_1_5000_025/73634_913786_M-34-1-B-b-3-1.tif'
coo = 'POLYGON ((711263.6400000000139698 621386.0999999999767169, 711268.6800000000512227 621386.6500000000232831, 711268.7299999999813735 621386.2600000000093132, 711274.7099999999627471 621386.8100000000558794, 711275.4200000000419095 621379.0500000000465661, 711265.0400000000372529 621377.4300000000512227, 711263.6400000000139698 621386.0999999999767169))'
coo_buffer = coo.buffer(3)

with rasterio.open(tiff) as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [coo_buffer], crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta
    out_meta.update(
        {   
            "crs": "epsg:2180",
            "driver": "GTiff",
            "height": out_image.shape[1],
            "width": out_image.shape[2],
            "transform": out_transform,
        }
    )
    with rasterio.open('/mnt/gis_matrix/geo_tiff_1_5000_025/roof.tif', "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)
```

I used gdal:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from osgeo import gdal

fname = 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73634_913786_M-34-1-B-b-3-1 (1).tif'
poly = 'POLYGON ((457842.63 453925.49, 457845.91 453916.83, 457834.66 453912.58, 457831.39 453921.24, 457836.09 453923.02, 457835.37 453924.92, 457838.99 453926.33, 457839.72 453924.39, 457842.63 453925.49))'

# Or if you want a file with the cropped data
g = gdal.Warp("C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/000009df-d809-469f-8709-908f832e51bf.tif", fname, 
              cropToCutline=True,
              cutlineSQL=f"select ST_GeomFromText({poly})",
              format="GTiff")
g = None # You need this to close the file and flush the dataset
```

My output is the same like the fname, I didn't get a polygon. Where is the problem?

Comment: I think you are looking for `gdal_warp`. There are many examples online and the documentation is good. Also look into [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257257/how-to-use-gdal-warp-cutline-option)

Comment: Is there a ```rasterio``` solution to this problem, or do we have to absolutely use  ```gdal ``` interface?

Comment: Have you considered making it from the command line? sometimes you can achieve it with less code

Answer (score 0):

Use `gdal.Warp`, and pass the geometry as part of a SQL query. If you don't need to change the polygon in your Python code, just dump into a GeoJSON and read it using the `cutlineDSName` option for `gdal.Warp`.
You also need a fake GeoPackage or Spatialite file as a source for the cutline. It doesn't matter what the file is, but unless you have that, you won't get GDAL to use the SQLITE SQL dialect for the query.

```py
fname = '/mnt/gis_matrix/geo_tiff_1_5000_025/73634_913786_M-34-1-B-b-3-1.tif'
poly = 'POLYGON ((
711263.6400000000139698 621386.0999999999767169, 
711268.6800000000512227 621386.6500000000232831,
711268.7299999999813735 621386.2600000000093132, 
711274.7099999999627471 621386.8100000000558794, 
711275.4200000000419095 621379.0500000000465661, 
711265.0400000000372529 621377.4300000000512227, 
711263.6400000000139698 621386.0999999999767169))'
# If you just want the data on an e.g. numpy array:
data = gdal.Warp("", fname,
              cutlineDSName="/tmp/world.gpkg",
              cropToCutline=True,
              cutlineSQL=f"select ST_GeomFromText({poly})",
              format="MEM").ReadAsArray()
# Or if you want a file with the cropped data
g = gdal.Warp("my_funky_output_file.tif", fname, 
              cropToCutline=True,
              cutlineDSName="/tmp/world.gpkg",
              cutlineSQL=f"select ST_GeomFromText({poly})",
              format="GTiff")
g = None # You need this to close the file and flush the dataset
```

Here, if you read `data` as a numpy array, it'll be a square array of pixels. The pixels outside the polygon will be set to fill value (you can change that if you want).

Comment: I used your code and I got output the same like fname, I didn't get a polygon. I have just edited my post, could you look?

Comment: One question: do the raster and polygon share projection? If not, you may need to reproject one or the other. In the SQL, you can use  `ST_Transform` with a suitable EPSG projection code to match the projection of the raster file.

Comment: Any Solution to problem yet??I am also trying same and getting same output raster see my question here,  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404790/how-to-cut-a-raster-exactly-to-geometry-of-a-irregular-polygon

Comment: OK, I  noticed I had forgotten a detail: you need a sample GPKG or spatialite file so that the spatialite SQL dialect mode is started. Should now work.

Answer (score 0):

```
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = outputpath, # directory output
          srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = intputpath, # directoy intput
          cutlineDSName    = shapefile or geojson, # vector file
          cropToCutline    = True, # Select True
          copyMetadata     = True, # optional
          dstNodata        = 0)    # if you have values of zeros
```