# How to cut a raster exactly to Geometry of a irregular polygon?

Tags: python, pyqgis, gdal, gdalwarp

To cut a raster I saw some solutions suggesting gdalwarp with `cropToCutline` and `cutlineSQL` options.

```
poly = item.geometry.asWkt()
ds = 'raster.tif'
sql = f"select ST_GeomFromText('{poly}',4326)"
finaloutwarp = 'warped.tif'  
g = gdal.Warp(finaloutwarp, ds, cropToCutline=True, cutlineSQL=sql, format="GTiff")
g = None
```

But the output is the same as the input `ds` dataset. Not sure where it is going wrong.
Here `item.geometry` is a `QgsRubberband` geometry.
Any other method is also welcome.

Comment: In `ArcGIS` you can use the tool `extract by mask`.

Comment: I need to plug this code in a QGIS Plugin so no option of ArcGIS

Comment: Is there any error thrown. You have a type in your query, it should be an space between `select` and `ST_GeomFromText`

Comment: @Francisco No that was just a typo in the question.Edited now.

Comment: is your raster in epsg:4326?

Comment: You need a GPKG/Spatialite file to select SQLite dialect. It doesn't need to be related or anything. See update to https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/404790/2948

Answer (score 2):

```
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = outputpath, # directory output
          srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = inputpath, # directoy intput
          cutlineDSName    = shapefile or geojson, # vector file
          cropToCutline    = True, # Select True
          copyMetadata     = True, # optional
          dstNodata        = 0)    # if you have values of zeros
```